# slow performance using xarray.DataArray.quantile() on large dataset

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I am using `xarray` in pyhton (Spyder) to read large NetCDF-files and process them.

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('my_file.nc')
```

`ds` has the following dimensions and variables:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time: 62215, points: 2195)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1980-04-01 ... 2021-09-30T21:00:00
Dimensions without coordinates: points
Data variables:
    longitude  (time, points) float32 ...
    latitude   (time, points) float32 ...
    hs         (time, points) float32 ...
```

I want to calculate the 95th percentile of the variable `hs` for each specific point, and generate a new variable to the dataset: 
`hs_95      (points) float32`

I do this with one line of code:

```
ds['hs_95'] = ds.hs.quantile(0.95, dim='time')
```

Where `ds.hs` is a `xr.DataArray`.

But it takes a very long time to run. Is there anything I can do to make it run faster? Is `xarray` the most convenient to use for this application?

Comment: great question, and welcome to stack overflow! this is totally right. note, though, that it doesn't look like your data has been read into memory yet. xarray loads data from netCDFs lazily, only reading in the parts of the data which are requested for an operation. So the first time you work with the data, you'll be getting the read time + the quantile time. the quantiling may still be slow, but for a real benchmark you should first load the dataset with `ds = ds.load()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Loading the data with ```ds.load()``` takes quite some time but after that the quantile operation is fast.

Comment: nice! yeah... loading 1.5 GB into memory will do that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `skipna=False` in `xarray.DataArray.quantile()` method? This could help a bit.

Comment: this can actually help quite a lot - the methods being called under the hood are [`np.nanquantile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanquantile.html) vs. [`np.quantile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html), and [`nanquantile` is hundreds of times slower than `quantile` when operating over a subset of dims](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16575). but you do need to be careful - using `skipna=False` will result in incorrect results if there are nans in the data.

Comment: nice job with your first answer! welcome to stack overflow :D

Answer (score 1):

Migrating my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73716477/slow-performance-using-xarray-dataarray-quantile-on-large-dataset?noredirect=1#comment130180218_73716477) into an answer...

xarray loads data from netCDFs lazily, only reading in the parts of the data which are requested for an operation. So the first time you work with the data, you'll be getting the read time + the quantile time. The quantiling may still be slow, but for a real benchmark you should first load the dataset with [`xr.Dataset.load()`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.load.html), e.g.:

```py
ds = ds.load()
```

or alternatively, you can load the data and close the file object together with [`xr.load_dataset(filpath)`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.load_dataset.html).

That said, you should definitely heed @tekiz's [great advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73716656/3888719) to use `skipna=False` if you can - the performance improvement can be on the order of 100x if you don't have to skip NaNs when quantiling (if you're sure you don't have NaNs).